# How can I re render a component? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

im new in react native, and im doing a note block, the problem now its that once i click save, it saves it to the array but when i get back to home screen, where i show the notes that are saved it doesnt show the last one, until i re load the entire project, how can I do to re render it? i have seen that i have to use this.forceUpdate(), but it doesnt working either, heres the code:

this is the home screen, the first screen the user will see, it shows the notes that are saved calling the component Notes

```
render() {
    return (
        <>
        <View style = {this.styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text style = {this.styles.Text}>Welcome to home!</Text>
            </View>
            <Notes></Notes>
            <View style = {this.styles.View}>
                <Button title = "Create new note" styles = {this.styles.Button} onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Create_note")}></Button>
            </View>
            <View style = {this.styles.View}>
                <Button title = "Notes" styles = {this.styles.Button} onPress = {() =>this.props.navigation.navigate("See_notes")}></Button>
            </View>
        </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

heres the component Notes:

```
class Notes extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        array_notes: [],
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetch_notes();
}

fetch_notes = async() => {
    try {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("array_notes");
        if (data != null) {
            const array_notes = JSON.parse(data);
            this.setState({array_notes: array_notes});
        }else {
            console.log("with no data");
        }
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render() {
   return (
       <>
       <View style = {this.styles.View}>
            <FlatList data = {this.state.array_notes} renderItem = {({item}) => (<Text style = {this.styles.Text}>{item.title}</Text>)} keyExtractor = {(item) => item.title}></FlatList>
       </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

and heres the create a new note screen, where the user type a new note:

```
class Create_note extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        title: "",
        content: "",
    }
  }

save_Data = async() => {
    try {
        const array_notes = await AsyncStorage.getItem("array_notes");
        if (array_notes === null) {
            const array_notes = [];
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("array_notes", JSON.stringify(array_notes));
        }else {
            const new_note = {'title': this.state.title, 'content': this.state.content};
            const array_notes = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("array_notes"));
            array_notes.push(new_note);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("array_notes", JSON.stringify(array_notes));
        }
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

}
render() {
    return  (
        <>
        <Text style = {this.styles.Text }>Welcome to Shum Note!</Text>
        <View>
            <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_title} placeholder = "Title" multiline = {true} maxLength = {80} onChangeText = {(title) => this.setState({title: title})}></TextInput>
            <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_content} placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true} onChangeText = {(content) => this.setState({content: content})}></TextInput>
            <Button title = "Save" onPress = {this.save_Data}></Button>
        </View>
        <View style = {this.styles.back_Button}>
            <Button title = "Go back home" onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}></Button>
        </View>
        </>    
    );
}
```

once i saved the new note and press the go back home it doesnt show the last one until like i said, i reload the entire project, but something curious, is if i go to create_note screen it will re render each time, but it doesnt happend with home, why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to **pass in fetch_notes** as a prop in Create_note.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Create_note", fetch_notes: this.fetch_notes)
```

In your Create_note get the function from navigation.

```
 const { fetch_notes} = this.props.route.params; //https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/
```

After saving the note you have to call it like this: **this.props.fetch_notes()**

Comment: what? sorry didnt understand :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add `the.props.navigation.addListener`. When you are back from next screen to previous screen API calling because of addListener focus on current screen and UI is render because of state changes.

```
componentDidMount() {  
     
    this.focusListener =
this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {

     this.fetch_notes() 

      }); 
    
      }
```

Comment: already solved it, the problem is that this.fetch_notes its a function that is storage in Notes.js, and its a class, and im new i react so i dont how to use that function outside of the class, the solution that i made was using that function in home and passing it by props to Notes to create the components and then when i click save execute the function this.fetch_notes that i pass to create_note by navigation